# Procedure to search for string in XML column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a procedure that I want to use to search through a xml column and return the value I search for.  For now I just want it to return the value itself.  As it is now, it is returning the correct expected number of row, but the returned value is null!  I added the cast, but it returns the same!

Any ideas of how to get the searched string to return in stead of just null?  Thanks!

[image]

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FindString]
    @findString NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (Default 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' )

SELECT CAST(x.value('Value[1]', 'varchar(30)') As varchar(30)) As Value

FROM dbo.XmlTable x

CROSS APPLY x.XmlDocument.nodes('/*') a(x)

WHERE XmlDocument.exist('//*/text()[contains(., sql:variable("@findString"))]') = 1

    RETURN
END


GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FindString]
    @findString NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (Default 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' )

SELECT CAST(x.value('.', 'varchar(30)') As varchar(30)) As Value

FROM dbo.XmlTable x

CROSS APPLY x.XmlDocument.nodes('//*[contains(text()[1], sql:variable("@findString"))]') a(x)

    RETURN
END


GO
```